# Why is the Xilium.CefGlue WPF example so slow to load pages?

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded

The [Xilium.CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home) provides some sample projects for showing web pages within a Chromium Embedded Framework container.

The sample WPF application, *CefGlue.Samples.WpfOsr*, loads pages **very** slowly. You can see in the debug window that it makes extremely slow progress reading the page resources (html, css, javscript) — more than an order of magnitude slower that loading the same page in a browser (i.e. about 10 seconds for my page that includes jquery & angularjs).

On the other hand, the sample Windows Forms application, *CefGlue.Client*, does not show that same problem.

**Why is the WPF sample so slow, and is that a problem with WPF use of CEF in general, Xilium's CefGlue.WPF specifically, or something that can be fixed?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slowdown is caused by the WPF sample using a more verbose logging setting than the Windows Forms sample.

In *CefGlue.Samples.WpfOsr/Program.cs*, line 45 looks like this:

```
LogSeverity = CefLogSeverity.Verbose,
```

You can speed up the page load performance by changing it to a less frequent logging level, e.g.

```
LogSeverity = CefLogSeverity.Warning,
```

Comment: Use release CEF build.
Logging in CEF can't dramatically change how fast page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @fddima. I can't comment on why exactly the logging setting was affecting things so much (as I don't know why)—really, what I was experiencing is **unreasonably** slow; but the first thing I tried was Release build (using the Release libcef.dll from the Xilium binaries), and it was still slow as I described above.

Comment: Probably new versions perform more logging than in past. But i'm any way doesn't see any difference in performance on 'default' settings. So it is strange. Thanks any way for question.

Comment: Same for me, I'm using Release builds for every project and Offscreenrendering was extremly slow. Deactivating the logging makes it blazing fast. :)

Answer (score 3):

WPF sample uses off-screen rendering technique. But i think, that you are use debug CEF builds, which contains lot of asserts. Just use release CEF build. Also may be exists some problems with proxy resolving. Or you are doing something wrong. For me it is work fast even inside VM's on not top hardware.